# How to set Multistore url like https://mywebsite.com/ca/ in magento2

Tags: magento2, multistore

I created store in admin Now i want to hit like below urls and I created folder in magento root directory 'ca' and 'fr' and 'au' folder and also put .htaccess and index.php file Now what is the next step?
'ca', 'fr', 'au' is my stores code
How can I configure store urls like below?
Please Help it's urgent!

> Canada             https://mywebsite.com/ca/
>   France              https://mywebsite.com/fr/
>   Australia           https://mywebsite.com/au/

URLS GOING to 404 error: Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create storeviews. You must go to:

> Stores -> Settings -> All Stores -> Create Storeview

Then there you can create the storeviews you desire.

You keep the store same as Default and you fill in the gaps.

Bear in mind that the code will be the one appears in the URL.

Then you will be able to make changes in the web choosing between storeviews and being able to make differences between these stores.

Comment: Before Urls working after i created ca folder for sitemap.xml for storewise after that store url going 404 so how i run url with store code

Comment: I recommend you using storeviews instead of sitemap. I don't know how sitemap works. Or explore other solutions.

Comment: i put .htaccess file or index.php in ca folder [ca folder for canada store view] but client saying that he want sitemap.xml store wise so i create ca folder and generate sitemap.xml for canada store view after that store url going 404 Before generate sitemap ULR'S was working fine

Comment: I don't know about sitemap. I have never used it. Sorry

Comment: I want say that 
store code = ca and country code folder = ca

Comment: i followed https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202135/magento-2-multistore-url-giving-404-error

Comment: I want do same but not success

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step. It may be helpful for you :

- On the Admin Panel, go **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.
- On the left panel, under **General**, select **Web**.
- In the upper-left corner, choose the **Store View** to check the new
  store you added.
- Hit OK to verify the scope switching.
- Open the **Base URLs** section,
- Clear the Use Website checkbox, that is next to the Base URL field.
- Change the **Base URL** for the store.
- Open the **Secure Base URLs** section below to set the store’s secure URL
  if needed.
- **Save Config** to complete.

Comment: Before Urls working after i created ca folder for sitemap.xml for storewise after that store url going 404 so how i run url with store code

Comment: check permission of that folder.

Comment: I followed https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202135/magento-2-multistore-url-giving-404-error

Comment: I want do same but not success